# how to write xpath with a variable

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a `xpath= //*[@id='00QE000000gQ9fv_ACTION_COLUMN']/a[2]/span`
in this xpath `00QE000000gQ9fv` is dynamic and `_ACTION_COLUMN` remains same.
I stored `00QE000000gQ9fv` in a String variable as `recordId` i.e 
`String recordId = 00QE000000gQ9fv`
Now i want a xpath which contains `recordId` variable.

Comment: Please post the html. I am not able to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your xpath will be - `//*[contains(@id,'_ACTION_COLUMN')]/a[2]/span`

Make sure `_ACTION_COLUMN` is unique or is the first element in your html so that u grab hold of the right element.

Edit 1 according to your comment.

Try this: `//*[contains(@id,'"+recordId +"')]/a[2]/span`

or

`//*[@id='"+ recordId +"_ACTION_COLUMN']/a[2]/span`

Comment: Thanx Ramesh, But the thing is i need to use the recordId variable in this xpath because i need to delete the record based on the redordId